# In Ted 2, Ted is arguing with a male and female neighbour. What language is female neighbour speaking?

Tags: ted-2

In Ted 2, Ted is arguing with a male and female neighbour. What language is that female neighbour speaking?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [WIKI transcript](http://transcripts.wikia.com/wiki/Ted_2), it's Portuguese.

> Ted: Oh, for Christ’s sake! [Ted opens the window and shout down to
>   the neighbor] You shut the fuck up!
>
> Boston Neighbor: Why do not you
>   come down and make me, tough guy?
>
> Ted: Yeah, why don’t you come up
>   here and make me come down there, tough guy?
>
> Boston Neighbor: I am
>   gonna come up there and I’m gonna kick your fucking ass!
>
> Ted: I want
>   you to try, asshole! Get your ass up here and kick my ass!
>
> **[a
>   Portuguese neighbor opens her window and shouts at them in Portuguese]**
>
> Boston Neighbor: Shut the fuck up you stupid idiot! **[directed to
>   Portuguese neighbor]**
>
> Ted: This is a classy neighborhood, people are
>   trying to sleep!
>
> Boston Neighbor: Shut the fuck up! **[the Portuguese
>   neighbor closes her window]** Hey, I’m really sorry!
>
> Ted: Yeah, me too.
>
> Boston Neighbor: She’s worse than us.
>
> Ted: Yeah, she’s our enemy now.